# How can I sorting case insensitive by realm?

Tags: android, sorting, realm, lowercase

I want to sort all members but starting with a lowercase letter to the end.

How can I sorting all members case insensitive?

```
Sorted members {
Alice
John
Olive
ashley -->
}
```

Realm version : 5.0.0

```
RealmResults<Member> allMembers = mRealm.where(Member.class).sort("name").findAll();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do case-sensitive *queries* by default.

If you want to sort case-insensitive, then you should store a second field that is full lowercase.

```
private String name;

@Index
private String nameLowerCase;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    if(name != null) {
        nameLowerCase = name.toLowerCase();
    } else {
        nameLowerCase = null;
    }
}
```

And

```
mRealm.where(Member.class).sort("nameLowerCase").findAll();
```

Comment: oh, *sort* case insensitive. Right. Updated.